# How to get differeces in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a Dataset called Chun analysis

see a sample of the dataset below.

| Aug | Sept |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| 9887 | 9887 |
| 9888 | 9888 |
| 9889 | 9889 |
| 9890 | 9890 |
| 9891 | 9891 |
| 9892 | 3223 |
| 9893 | 3223 |
| 9894 | 3223 |
| 9895 | 3223 |
| 9896 | 3223 |
| 9897 | 3223 |
| 9898 | 6563 |
| 9899 | 6563 |
| 9900 | 6563 |
| 9901 | 6563 |
| 6563 | 6563 |
| 6563 | 6563 |
| 6563 | 6563 |
| 6563 | 6563 |
| 6563 | 6563 |
| 6563 | 6563 |
| 6563 | 6563 |
| 6563 | 6563 |
| 6563 | 6563 |

What I want is to calculate the count and percentage of numbers in Aug that's not in Sept,
2. calculate new numbers in Sept that is not in Aug and the numbers in Aug and Sep in count and percentage

any R package is welcome but I will prefer tidyverse or dplyr package

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `%in%` to find the matches from `Aug` column values to `Sept`, negate (`!`) to the non-matching elements as a logical vector, get the `sum` to return the count.  For percentage, do the same except that we use `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    summarise(Aug_cnt = sum(!Aug %in% Sept), 
              Sep_cnt = sum(!Sept %in% Aug), 
              Aug_perc = 100 * mean(!Aug %in% Sept), 
              Sep_perc = 100 * mean(!Sept %in% Aug) )
```

---

Or use `setdiff` with `length`

```
df1 %>% 
    summarise(Aug_cnt = length(setdiff(Aug, Sept)),
              Sep_cnt = length(setdiff(Sept, Aug)),
              Aug_perc = Aug_cnt/n() * 100, 
              Sep_perc = Sep_cnt/n() * 100)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Aug = c(9887L, 9888L, 9889L, 9890L, 9891L, 9892L, 
9893L, 9894L, 9895L, 9896L, 9897L, 9898L, 9899L, 9900L, 9901L, 
6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L
), Sept = c(9887L, 9888L, 9889L, 9890L, 9891L, 3223L, 3223L, 
3223L, 3223L, 3223L, 3223L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 
6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```